# Get objects of objects in one query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails-application based on Postgresql I am trying to limit the database queries and general iterations in my web application and I am looking for a way to in ONE query do this.

Relation:
- Product has_and_belongs_to_many Categories

What I want to do is to find all the Products related to all the Categories which in turn is included by my main Product. E.g. I have

```
@blue_car
@blue_car.categories #=> "blue, car"
Category.find(blue).products #=> "Blue car, Blue boat"
Category.find(car).products #=> "Blue car, Green car"
```

so the result I want to get from @blue_car is "Blue car, blue boat, blue car, green car".

I do this today with an iteration:

```
product_list = []
Product.categories.each do |product|
product_list << product.categories
end
```

Instead, I would like to solve this in ONE query, it should be possible using the right type of join, right?

Like this (which doesn't work): `product_list = @blue_car.categories.products`

I don't know if it complicates it but I do some filtering so the final query would have to be more like

```
product_list = @blue_car.categories.where(:category_foo => "bar").products.where(:product_stuff => "things")
```

Any elegant suggestions?

Comment: `@blur_car.categories #=> "blue, car"`

Are these names of categories?  i.e does category have a name field?

Comment: Yes, "blue" and "car" are the names of the categories whereas "blue car" is the name of a certain product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: { name: @blur_car.categories } )
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thanks! I did alter it slight to be: Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: @blur_car.categories.pluck(:id) } ). Note that I used :categories and not :category (which did not work). You may want to update that in your answer.

Comment: Yes you're right `id` is much more efficient :) I was under the impression that name is the foreign key

Comment: I added a follow up question to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134666/rails-get-objects-of-objects-with-duplicates . Do you know how to solve that as well?

Comment: @Christoffer Hi I added an answer there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've put something like this should work.

```
Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: @blur_car.categories})
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that I get: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "category"