# Rails - get objects of objects WITH duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I received some really good help in solving an issue in which I needed to get [objects from objects in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121312/get-objects-of-objects-in-one-query-in-rails). That worked like a charm.

This is a follow up to that question. I chose to create a new question to this since the last one was answered according to my previous specification. Please do refer to that previous question for details.

Basically, I wanted to get all the objects of multiple objects in one single query. E.g. if a Product has several Categories which in turn has several Products, I want to get all the Products in that relation, easier (and erronously) put:

```
all_products = @my_product.categories.products
```

This was solved with this query. It is this query I would (preferably) like to alter:

```
Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: @my_product.categories.pluck(:id) } )
```

Now, I realized something I missed using this solution was that I only get a list of unique Products (which one would expect as well). I would however like to **get a list with possible duplicates as well**.

Basically, if a "Blue, Electric Car" is included in categories ("Blue", "Electric" and "Car") I would like to get three instances of that object returned, instead of one unique.

I guess this does not make Rails-sense but is there a way to alter the query above so that it does not serve me a list of unique objects in the returned list but rather the "complete" list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want duplicates, just change `includes` to `joins`, (I tested this just now). `joins` will essentially combine (inner-join) the two tables giving you a list of records that are all unique (per Product and Category). `includes` does eager loading which just loads the associated tables already but does an outer-join, and therefore, the retrieved records are also unique (but only per Product).

```
Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: @my_product.categories.pluck(:id) } )
```

Answer (score 2):

The `includes` method of AREL will choose between two strategies to make the query, one of which simply does two distinct query and the other one does an INNER JOIN.
In both cases the products will be distinct.

You have to do manually a right outer join:

```
Product.joins('RIGHT JOIN categories ON categories.product_id = products.id').where(categories: { id: @my_product.categories.pluck(:id) } )
```

adds also `.preload(:categories)` if you want to keep the eager loading of the categories.